# WCF self-hosted service with transport security (Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream.)

Tags: wcf, security, self-hosting, netsh

I have a self-hosted service that I want to add transport security to.
I've set WSHttpBinding.SecurityMode to Transport and the ClientCredentialType to HttpClientCredentialType.None.
I've created a certificate and set it to my host with
ServiceHost.Credentials.ServiceCertificate.SetCertificate()
I've also registered it using
netsh http add sslcert ipport=127.0.0.1:80 certhash=[MyCertHash] certstorename=MY appid=[TheGuidOfTheAppTahtRunsTheService] verifyclientcertrevocation=disable

I'm getting the following error message whenever I try to call the service:
"Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream."

Does this mean the the client and server try to authenticate each other? How can I disable it? 
To make things clear, I do not want to install a certificate at the client, I'm not looking for any authentication atm, just securing the messages content, if that's even possible.

Comment: Add logging to your WCF server and use the Service Trace Viewer from Vista SDK to see what the exact error is!

Do not overlook the probability that the error is in your code.

Comment: The service works fine without transport security.

Answer (score 2):

This MSDN [post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/ca954f2c-4015-41b9-bc6b-81a6c901b6c2/) may help solve your problem. The initial request in the post is to configure a different security mode than yours but they switch to Transport mode for troubleshooting and that info should apply to your situation.

If what you describe is all you've done to install the certificate then you're missing a few steps. The post outlines the process to get a valid certificate installed. Good luck!!

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not using the certificate for authentication, just for encryption, so it's quite a different scenarion.
Anyway, I've added the cert to the TrustedPeople but it didn't help.

Answer (score 2):

Certificates can be a pain in the ass some times to get working. First thing you should always do with WCF is turn on tracing:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx

Then, you can use SVCTraceViewer to view the exceptions that your service is generating behind the scenes and get a little insight into what is happening, which is a must with many WCF problems. 9 out of 10 times, the trace will tell you everything you need to know.

Also, make sure that both the client and the server have the certificate configured, since the certificate needs to be installed on both machines.

Answer (score 2):

I was trying to track down this same error, and came across this post. WCF tracing doesn't help as the error appears on the client side in the HTTP stack, and on the server side the request is rejected before it ever makes it to the WCF layer.

I found that I wasn't being thorough enough. Make sure all the following conditions are met. I had some but not all of these properly set up:

1. The server's certificate issuer has a valid and matching issuing
   trusted root CA on the same machine.
2. The server certificate subject name matches the machine name
   exactly, and the machine name the client is accessing matches as well ("localhost" vs the server's `Environment.MachineName` value)
3. The server certificate's thumbprint
   has been set by an Administrator
   using the following command (use
   `netsh` equivalent for newer versions of Windows)

   ```
   httpcfg set ssl -i 0.0.0.0:{port} -h {thumbprint}
   ```
4. This client also has the same valid issuing root CA certificate on the client machine.

Here's a good reference: [SSL with Self-hosted WCF Service](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/WCFSSL.aspx).